# Does commenting out some code decreases the size of apk?

Tags: java, android, size, apk, filesize

I have some code in my files which is no longer in use.

I don't want to remove it completely as it can come handy at later stage. So, can I just comment it out?

Will doing this keep the size of the `apk` same or decreases it? In other words, Should I remove the code or just comment it out if I want the size of the `apk` to be decreased?

Please let me know.

Comment: Ever heard of using source control?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Nope. Please tell me more about it.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Thanks! I want to know that whether comments contributes in the size of an apk or not.

Answer (score 3):

No,they don't and there is no effect on apk file.Commented code is not included in the compiled code.
The comments are removed before the class file is created. The compiler is responsible for removing comments and them are not included in the final files.

Just try to create a class file with coments and then use any decompiler to check the .class file.

Comment: I want to know that whether they contribute in the size of an `apk` or not.

Comment: They don't @HammadNasir